# Ext JS 6 select tree node parent in huge TreePanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a huge Tree with a lot of nodes. My usecase is the following:
After deleting a node I should select the parent of the deleted node.
I am using the below code

```
this.treeController.getTree().ensureVisible(parentOfTheDeletedNode.getPath());
```

to select the parent. 
I am receiving an error inside of the Ext JS 6 framework that the requested node can't be find. I debugged the framework code and I reached here:

```
getById: function(id, asDom) {
        // for normal elements getElementById is the best solution, but if the el is
        // not part of the document.body, we have to resort to querySelector
        var dom = DOC.getElementById(id) || this.dom.querySelector(Ext.makeIdSelector(id));
        return asDom ? dom : (dom ? Ext.get(dom) : null);
    };
```

In the watch window of the Developer Tools(Browser) I tried out manually to execute the `this.dom.querySelector` method with the requested `id`. I received the same result, the element wasn't find inside the `this.dom` element.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post a test case.

Comment: It isn't so easy to post a test case from the existing code because I am encountering this issue in a big application. I need to create a test case from scratch. Until I will create this test case any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Not really, you haven't posted any useful debugging info other than it can't find some DOM node.